# Understanding the conversion of different numeral systems

Tags: binary, number-systems

I know how to convert different numeral systems to other numeral systems, but I would like to understand how this methods are working.

As an example: 
Convert the decimalnumber 163 to binary:

163:2= 81 R1
81:2=  40 R1
40:2=  20 R0
20:2=  10 R0
10:2=  5  R0
5:2=   2  R1
2:2=   1  R0
1:2=   0  R1

Result: 10100011

Why does the division with remainder results in the binary numeral system?

Comment: Because the decimal 23 is $2 \times 10^1 + 3 \times 10^0$. Thus, dividing it by 10 you get the rightmost decimal digit. And so on.

Comment: If we follow the calculation backwards, we multiply with $2$ and add the next bit (beginning with $1$) , which is just the Horner-scheme to evaluate poynomials (in this case at $x=2$)